# How do I make a python library configurable? (Initialization)

Tags: python, configuration

I'm creating a python library that acts as library and not an app. It's a wrapper around a REST API that has complex responses and I want to abstract the parsing. The library can then be used by apps.

The REST API is around a SaaS offering so one configuration part would be the domain and another the api key. I'm aware I can create an ini file and use `configparser`. But that means I still need to pass the path of the config file to the library. A dict would however be preferable as that way the app can decide how to store the config. I also want to initialize the library exactly once and not have the options as method or constructor arguments (except for an initialization method).

How can I achieve that? Is it sensible to have the app require to call specific method like `config(options: dict)` before the library can be used?

EDIT:

Best analogy I can come up with is ORM for REST. Let's say there are Rooms, shelves and Books each backed by a set of API end points (GET, PUT etc). So I will want to create a class that wraps these calls for each item and each class like Book, Room etc needs access to the config.

An important thing is that these items are configurable in the system, eg. admins can add whatever properties to them they want and a GET call for example returns a list of properties with metadata about them (id, name, type etc). Hence the need for the wrapper.

Comment: Ship defaults in a config file with your library. Make overriding the defaults configurable programmatically - i.e via initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I usually make my configuration options as constructor params where the args are optional. If the value isn't overridden then I fetch the values from environment variables. This allows developers to easily override the configuration without any complex setup.

```py
class Api:
    def __init__(self, url=None, key=None):
        self.url = url or os.environ.get("MYAPP_URL", "safe default")
        self.key = key or os.environ.get("MYAPP_KEY", "safe default")
```

If you end up getting a large amount of config items that you need to pass around, I'd follow the same pattern, but have a config class:

```py
class ApiConfig:
    def __init__(self, url=None, key=None, user=None, region=None):
        self.url = url or os.environ.get("MYAPP_URL", "safe default")
        self.key = key or os.environ.get("MYAPP_KEY", "safe default")
        self.user = user or os.environ.get("MYAPP_USER", "safe default")
        self.region = region or os.environ.get("MYAPP_REGION", "safe default")

class Api:
    def __init__(self, config=None):
        self.config = config or ApiConfig()
```

Comment: OK. In my case I will have many "Api" classes for each set of end points. Best analogy I can come up with is ORM for REST. Let's say there are Rooms, shelves and Books each backed by a set of API end points (GET, PUT etc). So I will want to create a class that wraps these calls for each item. An important thing is that these items are configurable by the system, eg. admins can add whatever properties to them they want. Hence the complexity.

Comment: @beginner_ Is creating a gateway API feasible for your service? The idea would be to host a service (gateway) which is responsible for calling out to your other microservices/ rest api's in a unified way. Basically a smart proxy. Something like GraphQL might be an interesting fit for your use-case. https://graphql.org/ https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/graphql-as-an-api-gateway-to-micro-services/

Answer (score -1):

Well, here's an idea. How about writing your own config parser that uses dictionaries instead? You could write your config in JSON format and load it as a dictionary using `json.loads`. This way you can retrieve the configuration parameters from anywhere, including the web since JSON is web-friendly.